Как получить PCI DSS сертификат?
У меня есть сайт магазина на Django. Пытаюсь интегрироваться с сервисом платежной системы. Нужно отправлять банковские данные пользователя по API в платежную систему из формы оплаты на сайте. Однако мне сказали, что это запрещено и я должен перенаправлять пользователя на сайт платежной системы, где он заполняет данные, а затем возвращается обратно ко мне на сайт. Чтобы реализовать отправку данных напрямую требуется PCI DSS сертификация.
Как и где проходят PCI DSS сертификацию? В чем она заключается?

Это подтверждает что ваш сайт безопасен. Эту сертификацию делают в основном только банки и единицы магазинов. Делайте через редирект. Врятли в текущее время что-то получится сертифицировать
